# How to get the JSON path from element

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg, backbone.js

I have implemented a recursive javascript function to draw the following structure in an svg by reading a JSON schema as follows.

Is there a way to determine the JSON path of a selected node? Like, when the user clicks on a node (say `country:string`), is there a way to return the JSON path (as `person.address.country`)?

**UPDATE:** I'm using backbone models, so the solution in my mind is to keep track and add JSON path as an attribute of the node to later use. I'm looking for other direct methods.

```
{
  "title": "person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "first name": { "type": "string" },
    "last name": { "type": "string" },
    "age":{ "type":"number"},
    "birthday": { "type": "string", "format": "date-time" },
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "house number": { "type": "number" },
        "lane": { "type": "string" }
      }    
    },
        "city": { "type": "string" },
        "state": { "type": "string" },
        "country": { "type" : "string" }
      }    
    },
    "phone number": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "location": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "code": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "location",
          "code"
        ]
      }
    },
    "children": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "nickname":{"type":"string"}
  }
}
```

[image]

The recursive code(backbone function) is as follows:

```
//initiate
  var title = data.title || "Root";
  var count = this.traverseJSONSchema(data, title, 0, 0, this.get('tempParent'));

//function
traverseJSONSchema: function (root, rootName, level, rank, resultPane) {
                    var height = this.nodeHeight,
                            width = this.containerWidth,
                            margin = width / 6,
                            x = 0,
                            overhead = rank * margin,
                            y = level * height;
                    var tempParent = resultPane.append("g").attr("class", "nested-group");
                    if (root.type === "object") {
                        if (rootName !== "") {
                            var nodeText = rootName + ":" + root.type;
                            var node = new DataMapper.Models.Node({parent: tempParent, text: nodeText, x: x, y: y, type: this.get('type'), category: "object", height: height, width: width});
                            node.drawContainerNode(overhead);
                            rank++;
                            level++;
                        }
                        var nestedParent = tempParent.append("g").attr("class", "nested-group");
                        var keys = root.properties; //select PROPERTIES
                        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(keys).length; i++) {   //traverse through each PROPERTY of the object
                            var keyName = Object.keys(keys)[i];
                            var key = keys[keyName];
                            level = this.traverseJSONSchema(key, keyName, level, rank, tempParent);
                        }

                    } else if (root.type === "array") {
                        var keys = root.items; //select ITEMS
                        if (rootName !== "") {
                            var nodeText = rootName + ":" + root.type + "[" + keys.type + "]";
                            var node = new DataMapper.Models.Node({parent: tempParent, text: nodeText, x: x, y: y, type: this.get('type'), category: "array", height: height, width: width});
                            node.drawContainerNode(overhead);
                            rank++;
                            level++;
                        }

                        level = this.traverseJSONSchema(keys, "", level, rank, tempParent); //recurse through the items of array
                    } else if (["string", "integer", "number", "boolean"].indexOf(root.type) > -1) {    //when the type is a primitive
                        tempParent.classed("nested-group", false);
                        if (rootName !== "") {
                            var nodeText = rootName + ":" + root.type;
                            var node = new DataMapper.Models.Node({parent: tempParent, text: nodeText, x: x, y: y, type: this.get('type'), category: root.type, height: height, width: width});
                            node.drawContainerNode(overhead);
                            rank++;
                            level++;
                        }
                    }
                    return level;
                }
```

Comment: yes it is possible. you could include the object in text form for better understanding. please have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: just a hint, [JSON](http://json.org/) is always a string.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the advice. I was thinking of keeping track and adding the JSON path during the schema read as an attribute. Is there a direct way?

Comment: you have a mixed structure, sometimes with tile sometimes withoiut. what happens to properties without title?

Comment: @NinaScholz the function is initiated by calling *var title = data.title || "Root"* which will set the String "Root" if the title is undefined. Question in code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143692/read-json-schema-and-draw-tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a special treatment for concatination the path.

```js
function getPath(object, search) {
    function iter(o, p) {
        return Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
            if (k === key && o[k] && o[k].type === value) {
                path = p.concat(k).join('.');
                return true;
            }
            if (o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
                return iter(o[k],
                    k === 'properties' && !o.title ?
                        p :
                        p.concat(k === 'properties' && o.title ? o.title : k)
                );
            }
        });
    }

    var parts = search.split(':'),
        key = parts[0],
        value = parts[1],
        path;

    iter(object, []);
    return path;
}

var data = { title: "person", type: "object", properties: { "first name": { type: "string" }, "last name": { type: "string" }, age: { type: "number" }, birthday: { type: "string", format: "date-time" }, address: { type: "object", properties: { "street address": { type: "object", properties: { "house number": { type: "number" }, lane: { type: "string" } } }, city: { type: "string" }, state: { type: "string" }, country: { type: "string" } } }, "phone number": { type: "array", items: { type: "object", properties: { location: { type: "string" }, code: { type: "number" } }, required: ["location", "code"] } }, children: { type: "array", items: { type: "string" } }, nickname: { type: "string" } } };

console.log(getPath(data, 'country:string'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```